# Running SSH commands and shell scripts from Jmeter

Tags: ssh, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Does anybody knows how to execute series of commands over SSH from Jmeter. I used SSH Sampler as mentioned on http://www.technix.in/execute-linux-command-shell-script-apache-jmeter/#comment-8456 and was able to login to remote server with my own user. However, I want to do few more steps.  Not sure how I can do

1. Sudo to a different user – ‘sudo su – report’
2. Change to some directory
3. Run some shell script which is already there
4. The Shell script will produce some output file. I need to SFTP the output file from there to local Jmeter directory
5. Write some tests to verify the output file. THis can be done later but how to do first 4 steps.

The main problem I am facing is that I am not able to understand how I can run series of commands in SSH Sampler. I tried using ; and it worked. However I am not able to do Sudo and run shell script from there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!
Vivek

Answer (score 2):

As per [su command manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html)

> ```
>   -c, --command=command
>           Pass command to the shell with the -c option.
> ```

So you can substitute `sudo` with `su` and execute something like:

```
su -c "cd /some/directory && ./run_some_script" -s /bin/bash report
```

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) guide for more information.

Comment: Thanks @dmitri
However still "sudo su - report -c pwd" is not working. I added an SSH Sampler to Jmeter and then used hostname, user name and password to connect to a remote unix machine. That gets connected fine. However when I used Sudo command it doesnt worked.

Below is how my Jmeter plan looks like:

Comment: This is what I have configured in SSH Sampler in Jmeter:

Hostname - Unix_Server
Port - 22

user - VivekM
Password - xxxxx

execute Command - sudo su - report -c pwd

In View Result Tree I can see the server that it gets connected to my user but still Sudo doesnt work.

I then wrote a java program to do similar stuff. However in Java also it gets connected but while running sudo it give below error:

Connected
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
exit-status: 1
DONE

Comment: did I mention sudo anywhere?

Comment: No @Dmitri T

However from UNIX box I login from my user "a.vmalho" to report user in the following way. When I use below command it doesn't prompt me for password and then I can run the shell script with report user. I want to simulate the same functionality in Jmeter. Is this possible with SSH Sampler or if  Jmeter is not capable of this, then I will look for other tools. Many Thanks in Advance!!

[a.vmalho@d-breport-app01 ~]$ sudo su - report
-bash-4.1$ id
uid=5035(report) gid=5035(report) groups=5035(report) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
-bash-4.1$

Comment: I have resolved this & am able to connect to the UNIX box via SSH, but when I am running shell script its returning a return code of 127 ($?). Do you know what could be the reason.

The same script is running fine from the path. This is my Jmeter Command

cd nexnet/bin/;pwd;ls -lrt;sh nexnet.sh;echo $?

I tried to search 127 and it says “command not found” or “illegal command”. However the shell script is their on UNIX box at the path and when I login directly to the box I can run it. 

Can you please help if you have any ideas.

Comment: I have solved the above issue by adding "source ~/.bash_profile". Please ignore the above post.

However there is another issue now. I followed the Blazemeter link to add SSH Sampler and SSH SFTP Sampler in Jmeter. SSH Sampler is working fine as I just connected to the machine and executed the shell script. However SFTP Sampler is not visible in JMETER even after following all the steps like:

1. Downloaded "jmeter-ssh-sampler-0.1.0.jar" and copied to /lib/ext folder of JMeter installation.
2. Downloaded "jsch-0.1.51.jar" and copied to /lib/ folder of JMeter installation.
3. Restarted JMeter.

Comment: Manage to resolve this SFTP Sampler problem by following the below steps

https://sqatech.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/how-to-build-sftp-sampler-for-jmeter/#comment-7